# Easiest way to get a GAE datastore entry

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I put this a key and value into the datastore with the following command

```
data = MyData(db_token=request_token, db_secret=request_secret)
data.put()
```

It looks like this in the datastore

[image]

What would be the simplest way of retrieving db_secret if I know db_token? Ie

```
retreived_secret = db.somecommand(foo)
returns bar
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If db_token is unique, you can use it as a key

Save

```
data = MyData(key_name=request_token, db_secret=request_secret)
data.put()
```

Fetch

```
data = MyData.get_by_key_name(request_token)
```

Answer (score 0):

This assumes there is only one entity with db_secret = 'foo':

```
def retrieve_token(db_secret):
    try:
        entity = MyData.all().filter('db_secret =', db_secret).get()
        return entity.db_token
    except:
        return None
```

If there are multiple entities that match, you will need to add another filter.

Comment: I'm getting an error type object 'MyData' has no attribute 'filter'. What would be the cause of that?